# I am receiving his error when making a loan predictive system

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a loan dataset predictive system everything seems to work well but when I try to predict the outcome I keep getting this error at the end of the code,

"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:450: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but SVC was fitted with feature names
warnings.warn("

What could be the problem thank you.

My code:
`#importing the dependencies` import numpy as np
`import pandas as pd` import seaborn as sns from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split from sklearn import svm from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler```

#importing the dataset to pandas
`loan_dataset= pd.read_csv('/content/train_u6lujuX_CVtuZ9i (1).csv')``

#printing the first five rows of the dataset
`loan_dataset.head()`

#statistical measures
`loan_dataset.describe()` 
#number of values missing in each column
`loan_dataset.isnull().sum()`

#dropping missing values
`loan_dataset= loan_dataset.dropna()` 
#number of values missing in each column
l`oan_dataset.isnull().sum()` 
#label_Encoding
`loan_dataset.replace({"Loan_Status": {"N":0,"Y":1}},inplace=True)` 
#Dependent column values
`loan_dataset['Dependents'].value_counts()` 
#replacing the value of 3+ to 4
`loan_dataset= loan_dataset.replace(to_replace='3+', value=4)` 
#Education & Loan Status
`sns.countplot(x="Education",hue="Loan_Status", data= loan_dataset)` 
#marital status and loan status
`sns.countplot(x="Married",hue="Loan_Status", data= loa`n_dataset)

## convert categorical columns to numerical values

`loan_dataset.replace({'Married':{'No':0,'Yes':1},'Gender':{'Male':1,'Female':0},'Self_Employed':{'No':0,'Yes':1},`
'Property_Area':{'Rural':0,'Semiurban':1,'Urban':2},'Education':{'Graduate':1,'Not Graduate':0}},inplace=True)

#seperating the data and label
`X= loan_dataset.drop(columns=["Loan_ID","Loan_Status"],axis=1)`
`Y= loan_dataset["Loan_Status"]`
`print(X)`
`print(Y)`

#training the dataset
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.1,stratify=Y,random_state=3)

#imorting the support vector algorithm
classifier= svm.SVC(kernel="linear")

#training the support vector machine model
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)

#accuracy Score on training data
x_train_prediction= classifier.predict(x_train)
training_data_accuracy= accuracy_score(x_train_prediction,y_train)

```
print("Accuracy on training data:", training_data_accuracy)
```

## accuracy score on training data

```
x_test_prediction = classifier.predict(x_test)
test_data_accuray = accuracy_score(x_test_prediction,y_test)

print('Accuracy on test data : ', test_data_accuray)
```

#making a Predictive System
input_data= (1,1,1,1,0, 4583,1508.0,128.0,360.0,1.0,0)

#changing the input data to numpy array
input_data_as_numpy_array= np.asarray(input_data)

#reshaping the array as we are predicting for one instance
input_data_reshaped= input_data_as_numpy_array.reshape(1,-1)

```
data= input_data_reshaped

prediction= classifier.predict(data)
```

`

Comment: Your question is difficult to read.  It would be helpful if you included your code in a code block.  See [_"code fences"_](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for a convenient markdown option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trained your model with dataframe which had feature names(column names) and same with your test set where as when you are trying to predict with one instance it doesnot have any feature names hence it is throwing the error.
The fix for this would be to do one of the following.
1.Convert the instance into dataframe with same columns as original dataframe.
2.Train your model without feature names.
**model.fit(x_train.values,y_train.values)**